# Lowering mouse debounce time

Tags: mouse, hardware

i'm trying to lower my debounce time down to 4ms and i've been trying using xinput so
i did

```
xinput --list|grep -i mouse
```

and i got as output

```
 ↳ CUST0001:00 04F3:30AA Mouse              id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

then i tried

```
xinput --set-prop 14 "Evdev Debounce Delay" 4
```

but got

```
property 'Evdev Debounce Delay' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

i also tried with single quotes but same output please help``

```
xinput --list-props 14
```

output

```
Device 'CUST0001:00 04F3:30AA Mouse':
    Device Enabled (156):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (158): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (293):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (294):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (295):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (296):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (297):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (298): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (299): 3
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (300):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (301):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (304): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (305): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (306):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (307):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (308):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (309): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (310): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (278): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (279):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (280):    0, 0
    Device Node (281):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (282):    1267, 12458
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (311):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (312):   1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but this may not apply for all mice.
Type:

`sudo -i`

Enter your password then type:

`libinput list-devices | grep Device`

Then `cd` to the this directory by using this command:

`cd /usr/share/libinput`

Take note of your mouses name. Like for my wireless mouse it is `MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse`

Then type `touch local-overrides.quirks`

Now, to edit the file where you change the debounce time type:

`nano local-overrides.quirks`

Then edit the file according to your needs. Like this is an example:

`[Mouse Name]`

`MatchName=Mouse Name`

`ModelBouncingKeys=1`

Like for my mouse it will be:

`[MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse]`

`MatchName=MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse`

`ModelBouncingKeys=4`

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm!  What does the value mean?  You use values 1 and 4, but docs don't explain them -- https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.18.1/device-quirks.html

Comment: The MatchName is your mouses name the ModelBouncingKeys is the debounce time.

Comment: No repo to comment, but sorry to report that ModelBouncingKeys does not set a de bounce time, but instead Indicates that the device may send fake bouncing key events and timestamps can not be relied upon. So setting > 0 will allow bounced click event.

Comment: @RoyBellingan seems to be correct as per [official documentation](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html#list-of-currently-available-device-quirks): *"**ModelBouncingKeys** Indicates that the device may send fake bouncing key events."*